# API Requests should be made with Fetch or Node.js Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am new to Node. I saw many examples on Rapid API where we use the `axios` package to make requests to an API. But we can also do the same with `fetch` method in JavaScript frontend. So should I make API requests from frontend JavaScript using `fetch` or should I use my backend to make API requests using `axios`?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score -1):

1)**Axios** has url in request object while **Fetch** has no url in request object.

2)**Axios** is a stand-alone third party package that can be easily installed **while** Fetch is built into most modern browsers no installation is required as such.

3)**Axios** enjoys built-in XSRF protection but **Fetch** does not.

4)**Axios** uses the data property while **Fetch** uses the body property.

5)**Axios** data contains the object while **Fetch’s** body has to be stringified

6)**Axios** has the ability to intercept HTTP requests but **Fetch**, by default, doesn’t provide a way to intercept requests.

Go through this article and you will understand https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-fetch-and-axios-js-for-making-http-requests/

Comment: The article gives information about the two technologies. But I am still confused whether to make calls from frontend or backend. For example, I am making a Music Player using React. I want to make an API call to a website to get a song. So should I make the call from the React component in the frontend or should I make my backend make the call using Axios?

Comment: Please see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)